# What kind of structure is $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle 2+2i\rangle$?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, ideals, quotient-set

Consider the factor ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle 2+2i\rangle$, where $\langle 2+2i\rangle$ is the ideal of the Gaussian integers such that for all $z\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$, $z(2+2i)\in\langle 2+2i\rangle$. Since $2+2i+\langle 2+2i\rangle=\langle 2+2i\rangle$, we can say that $2+2i=0$.

From this, we can square both sides to say that $8=0$ in $\langle 2+2i\rangle$, and we can subtract $2$ from both sides to say that $2i=-2$. Note that we *cannot* say that $i=-1$, because this would imply that $1+i\in\langle 2+2i\rangle$. It is trivial to prove that this is not the case.

With this in mind, we can see that the order of $R$ is 16, and our 16 unique elements are in the set $S=\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, i, 1+i, 2+i, 3+i, 4+i, 5+i, 6+i,7+i\}$.

However, equipped with addition, multiplication, and the aforementioned identities, what exactly *is* $R$? It's clearly at least a group under addition. I *believe* it's also a ring, since distribution appears to work just fine, though there may be something I'm overlooking. I know that there are (to isomorphism) a finite number of distinct groups with a finite order. In particular, there are only 14 distinct groups of order 16. So, which of them is isomorphic to $R$?

A naive answer would be $\mathbb{Z}_8\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, but we can quickly see this is not the case. If it *was*, and we said $f$ is a homomorphism $f: R\rightarrow S=(a,b)$ where $a=\Re(z),b=\Im(z),$ for $z\in R$. Then, by definition of a homomorphism, we would say $f(z\times w)=f(z)\times f(w)$. We quickly see this is not true - consider the case where $z=1+i$. Here we find that $z^2=2i=-2=-2+8=6$, and as such, $f(z\times z)=f(6+0i)=(6,0)$. However, $f(z)\times f(z)=f(1+i)\times f(1+i)=(1,1)\times(1,1)=(1,1)$. Therefore, $f$ is *not* a homomorphism. For a similar reason we can also see that $R$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$, $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4$, or $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. What is left? What is it actually isomorphic to?

Comment: $(2+2i)(1-i)=4$ is in the ideal. So you only get 8 elements. It is a local ring - all non-units form the unique maximal ideal. $\Bbb{Z}[i]/\langle(1+i)^3\rangle$.

Comment: You're confusing the ideal with the quotient. $\langle 2+2i\rangle$ is the ideal generated by $2+2i$, it has an infinity of elements, not $16$. $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle 2+2i\rangle$ on the other hand is finite.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I think you meant $(-1+i)^3$

Comment: @jjagmath Thank you, I have edited my post to that effect

Comment: Regarding your statement *I believe it's also a ring*, that conclusion holds in vast generality, as an application of  theorem that you may already know: *For any ring $R$ and any ideal $I$, the ring operations on $R$ induce well-defined operations on $R/I$, and those operations give $R/I$ the structure of a ring (i.e. those operations satisfy all the ring axioms)*. So, for example, yes, the distributive law holds in $R/I$.

Comment: @GreginGre, that's the same ideal: multiply by $i^3$, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, as @LeeMosher commented, and as you suspected, yes, there is a natural ring structure on any quotient $R/I$ where $I$ is an ideal of a ring $R$.

And, as others commented, the cardinality of $\mathbb Z[i]/(1+i)^3$ is $8=2^3$ (not $16=2^4$). A little more generally, for any prime element $\varpi$ in $\mathbb Z[i]$ (note that $1+i$ is prime), the cardinality of $\mathbb Z[i]/\varpi^n$ is $\mathrm{cardinality}(\mathbb Z[i]/\varpi)^n$. There are various ways to argue this, and perhaps the clearest are not the most elementary...

So, yes, what are the possible abelian groups of order $8$? By the structure theorem, there are three, $\mathbb Z/2\oplus \mathbb Z/2\oplus\mathbb Z/2$, $\mathbb Z/2\oplus \mathbb Z/4$, and $\mathbb Z/8$.

For comparison, the quotient ring $\mathbb Z/8$ is, as an additive group, of course, $\mathbb Z/8$. That is, it's cyclic.

$\mathbb Z[i]/(1+i)^3$ is *not* cyclic, because $4\cdot 1=4=-(1+i)^4=0$, so $4\cdot a=4\cdot (1\cdot a)=(4\cdot 1)\cdot a=0\cdot a=0$. Still, $1+1=2\not=0$. So the additive group you have is $\mathbb Z/2\oplus \mathbb Z/4$.

As a ring, there is also an injection $\mathbb Z/4\to \mathbb Z[i]/(1+i)^4$, which we can follow by the quotient $\mathbb Z[i]/(1+i)^4\to \mathbb Z[i]/(1+i)^3$. Since $\mathbb Z/4$ is generated by $1$, and since its image in $\mathbb Z[i]/(1+i)^3$ is still order $4$, the map is injective. Thus, there's an injection of the ring $\mathbb Z/4$ to $\mathbb Z[i]/(1+i)^3$. But of course the image is not the whole thing.

There are fancier reasons for $\mathbb Z/2^n$ not to be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z[i]/(1+i)^n$, so it's not just a one-off. Namely, all such quotients are images of the $2$-adic completion $\mathbb Z_2$ of $\mathbb Z$, and of the $(1+i)$-adic completion $\mathbb Z[i]_{1+i}$ of $\mathbb Z[i]$. *If* there were a $\sqrt{-1}$ in $\mathbb Q_2$ (which there is not, as we can see already mod $4$), then these would be isomorphic. In contrast, for example, $\mathbb Z/5^n$ *is* isomorphic to $\mathbb Z[i]/(2+i)^n$, and in two different ways, because there *is* a $5$-adic $\sqrt{-1}$. :)

EDIT: as asked in a comment... while $\mathbb Z[i]/(1+i)^3\approx \mathbb Z/2\oplus \mathbb Z/4$ as abelian groups, can we determine whether or not these two things are isomorphic as *rings*? Methodology-wise, if we could hit upon a ring isomorphism by experiment, that'd be good; however, after failing at this for a while, we'd want a way to prove that they're *not* isomorphic as rings (without listing all the *group* isomorphisms and seeing that they fail to be ring isomorphisms). So, how to *characterize* these two rings? The $\mathbb Z[i]/(1+i)^3$ is a quotient of a commutative ring by a power of a prime ideal, so every zero divisor $x$ (meaning $x\not=0$, and there is $y\not=0$ such that $xy=0$) is actually *nilpotent* (meaning $x^n=0$ for some $n$). In contrast, $\mathbb Z/2\oplus \mathbb Z/4$ has non-nilpotent zero-divisors, such as $x=1\oplus 0$ and $y=0\oplus 1$: their product is $0$, but $x^2=x$ and $y^2=y$, etc.

Comment: Another way to express the quotient ring is as isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x] / \langle x^2+1, (x+1)^3 \rangle = \mathbb{Z}[x] / \langle x^2+1, 2x+2, 4 \rangle$.  Moreover, the sequence $x^2+1, 2x+2, 4$ is a Groebner basis of an ideal - which means that a polynomial is in the ideal if and only if when you divide by $x^2+1$ and take the remainder (of degree less than 2), then divide by $2x+2$ and take the remainder (of degree less than 2 and with $x$ coefficient either 0 or 1), then divide by 4, you get a remainder of 0 (with general possibilities being...

Comment: a polynomial of degree less than 2, with $x$ coefficient either 0 or 1 and constant coefficient one of 0,1,2,3).

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it's very helpful! However, I'm wondering - you mentioned that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(1+i)^3$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}/4$ *as an additive group*. Does this mean that the two are *not* isomorphic as rings? Because I can't seem to match the elements between sets up such that $f(z\times w)=f(z)\times f(w)$.